# How do I withdraw bitcoins from my MtGox account?

Tags: mtgox, spending

I've purchased a few bitcoins on MtGox. Now I'd like to spend them. **How can I actually spend the coins I purchased on MtGox?**

I've looked around mtgox.com for any indication of private keys, bitcoins addresses, hashes etc but didn't see anything. I'm fairly new to Bitcoin so there's probably something fundamental I don't quite understand yet.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy: you transfer them to other addresses. Go to Mt Gox, log in, select "Funding Options," select "Withdraw," select "Bitcoin" in the drop down box. You then can put in an amount, and an address of where you want to send your BC (bitcoins).

If you want to know where to spend them, check out https://www.bitcoinstore.com/ as an example. Personally, I am keeping mine as an investment - I have owned them for around 6 months and have made 150% returns. But you can also use them to pay friends around the world without paying a middleman.

Enjoy your cryptocurrency!

Answer (score 2):

Go to funding options -> withdraw funds -> choose withdraw method Bitcoin -> Enter the amount you want to transfer -> Enter a bitcoin adress

Preferably send to your wallet and use your wallet for purchases.

Answer (score 0):

DONT use Mt Gox. You will be forced to provide your passport plus other forms of identification, and then wait at least a month, if ever, (I know it says ten days but that is rubbish( for them to allow you to actually transfer the dollars or bitcoins from your Mt Gox account. I HAVE HEARD STORIES OF IT TAKING ANOTHER MONTH JUST TO DO A TRANSFER. They are completely incompetent.